# bootstrap php navigation bar highlight active

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, php-include

I have a problem with highlighting using php include.
Here's my navigation bar:

```
<?php
echo '
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-css.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/womsy/index.php">Womsy</a>
        </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li <?php echo $active[1] ?><a href="/womsy/home.php">Home</a></li>
                <li <?php echo $active[2] ?><a href="/womsy/blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                <li <?php echo $active[3] ?><a href="/womsy/projects.php">Projects</a></li>
                <li <?php echo $active[4] ?><a href="/womsy/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="/womsy/about.php">About</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</nav>';
$active[$current] = "class=active";
?>
```

I made this with bootstrap, and am trying to highlight via this: http://webdevjunk.com/coding/css/17/php-menu-includes-with-css-style-to-highlight-active-page-link/

```
<?php
$current = 1;
include 'php/menu.php';
?>
```

This is what I use on the page, but it doesn't highlight, but when I change the class in the `<li>` it does work.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: I still have this problem, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
function setActive($pageName)
{

    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $pageName)) {
        echo 'class="active"';
    }

}
//$pageName will be home ,blog,projects and contacts
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this actually works? can't make it work

Answer (score 1):

Declare page variable at the very top of each individual page.
Example: `<? $page="home";?>` goes at top of homepage and `<? $page="blog";?>` would go on top of blog page, etc.
For each list item in your menu add if statement with corresponding variable and active class.
Example:  `<ul><li class="<?if($page=="home"){?>active<?}?>"><a href="home.php"><b>Home</b></a></li><li class="<?if($page=="blog"){?>active<?}?>"><a href="blog.php"><b>Blog</b></a></li></ul>`
What this does is assign each page a variable. The variable is compared in the if statements in the nav bar to determine which li gets the active class.